# How to use multiple root element in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner to angular js. I am using angular with my bootstrap website with common header and footer. The below code working good.

The problem when I try to add the additional plugin root element like calendar plugin root element. I don't know **how to combine the one or more root element with multiple controller** .

Anyone help me to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
     angular.module('myApp', ['ui.rCalendar']);
     angular.module('myApp').controller('CalendarDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    -- --
    }
});
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

//menu
app.controller("menuController", function($scope) {
  $scope.menus = [  
    {
        title: "Home", 
        action: "/test/1"
    },
    {
        title: "About", 
        action: "about.php"
    },
    {
        title: "Module", 
        action: "#", 
        menus: [
          {
            title: "Calendar",
            action: "calendar.php"
          },
          {
            title: "Submenu 2",
            action: "#"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "Form", 
        action: "form.php"
    }
]
});
```

```
//iconbox   
app.controller('iconBox', function iconBox($scope) {
    $scope.servicebox = [
        {
            "icon"      : "fas fa-shopping-cart",
            "title"     : "ng-app",
            "desc"      : "The ng-app directive tells AngularJS that this is the root element of the AngularJS application. All AngularJS applications must have a root element. You can only have one ng-app directive in your HTML document." 
        },
        {
            "icon"      : "fas fa-desktop",
            "title"     : "ng-controller",
            "desc"      : "The ng-controller directive adds a controller to your application. In the controller you can write code, and make functions and variables, which will be parts of an object, available inside the current HTML element." 
        },
        {
            "icon"      : "fas fa-lock",
            "title"     : "$scope",
            "desc"      : "The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller). The scope is an object with the available properties and methods. The scope is available for both the view and the controller." 
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<header ng-controller="menuController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top main-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                    <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <ng-template ng-if="menu.menus.length > 0">
                            <a target="_self" href="{{menu.action}}" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">{{menu.title}}</a>
                            <ul ng-if="menu.menus" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.menus">
                                    <a target="_self" href="{{submenu.action}}" class="dropdown-item">{{submenu.title}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template ng-if="menu.menus.length == null">
                            <a target="_self" ng-click="" href="{{menu.action}}" class="nav-link">{{menu.title}}</a>
                        </ng-template>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</header>
```

```
<section class="sectionThree py-5" id="services" ng-controller="iconBox">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="section-header text-center">
            <h3>AngularJS</h3>
            <p>We are always with you to make your project.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center mt-4">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 pb-4 pb-md-0" ng-repeat="serviceitem in servicebox">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="{{serviceitem.icon}}"></i>
                    <h3>{{serviceitem.title}}</h3>
                    <p>{{serviceitem.desc}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your question, but I can tell you that this part is not correct;

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.rCalendar']);
```

You are basically using the setter for `'myApp'` module twice and overwriting the first one. If you need to have two modules, created a different module (different name) for the one with the calendar:

```
angular.module('myCalendar', ['ui.rCalendar']);
angular.module('myCalendar').controller('CalendarDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                -- --
}
```

and then insert it into your main module.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['myCalendar']);
```

Hope this helps!